# What could be wrong with this matrix multiplication benchmark (Matlab vs Numpy)?

Tags: python, performance, matlab, numpy, linear-algebra

Here's the code I wrote for comparing performance of numpy vs Matlab. It just measures the average time taken for matrix multiplication (1701x576 matrix M1  * 576x576 matrix M2).

**Matlab version** : (M1 is (1701x576) while M2 is (576x576) matrix)

```
function r = benchmark(M1,M2) 
    total_time=0;

    for i=1:4        
        for j=1:1500
            tic;
            a=M1*M2;
            tim=toc;
            total_time =total_time+tim;
        end     
    end        
    avg_time = total_time/4  
    r=avg_time
end
```

**Python version** :

```
def benchmark():
    iters = range(1500)
    for i in range(4):      
        for j in iters:         
            tic = time.time()
            a=M1.dot(M2);
            toc = time.time() - tic
            t_time=t_time+toc;
    return t_time/4
```

Matlab version takes almost ~**18.2s** , while Python takes ~19.3s . Ive repeated this test multiple times , and Matlab was always performing better than Python (even if smaller difference) in all cases . My understanding is Numpy uses efficient and compiled code for vector operations , and is supposed to be faster than Matlab.

Then , why could Matlab perform faster than Numpy ? The test was done on a 32 core machine . 
Where did I go wrong ? or is this expected for Numpy to be slower than Matlab.

Are there ways to improve the performance for Python ?

Edit : Updated the matlab code to fix the loop index/return value error . The error was the result of me trying to edit the names in the snipper to make it presentable just before posting(a bad idea everytime :) ).

Comment: The Python version will have a small amount of overhead due to repeated attribute lookups.  You could try doing `dot = M1.dot` outside the loop, and then `dot(M2)` inside your timed section.  Likewise pre-store `time = time.time`.  More generally, I'm not sure computing the exact same dot product 6000 times is a great benchmark.

Comment: I believe MATLAB also uses efficient and compiled code for vector operations. And I suggest computing *the minimum* of the durations, since that will give you the closest guess for performing the same computation. And tic/toc measures wall clock time and has some issues, `timeit` (already present in newer versions of MATLAB) should be more accurate.

Comment: Assuming that `M1` and `M2` are float arrays, the performance of `np.dot` will depend mainly on which BLAS library numpy is linked against at runtime, rather than on numpy itself. You can find this out from the output of `np.show_config()`. I believe that MATLAB uses Intel's Math Kernel Library (MKL).

Comment: Also, your MATLAB function returns `r` rather than `avg_time`

Comment: I've edited the code snippet to fix the return variable and loop index issue

Comment: Is there any structure in your matrices? Matlab chooses the routine depending on the matrices accordingly

Comment: What operating system did you use for this benchmark?

Comment: @percusse: I have never heard about that besides the difference between sparse and full matrices. Is there any reference or documentation for this?

Answer (score 0):

**[edited to remove the mention of loops; that was my mistake]**

Couple things--

First, the multicore nature of the machine doesn't really matter unless you're explicitly using those extra cores (or linking NumPy against a BLAS library that uses multiple cores -- thanks @ali_m). If you're not, it'll run about as fast on a 32-core machine as it will on a 4-core machine (assuming the clock speeds of the cores themselves are roughly equal).

Second, using purely off-the-shelf Matlab vs off-the-shelf NumPy, [Matlab generally beats out NumPy](http://rlhick.people.wm.edu/posts/comparing-the-speed-of-matlab-versus-pythonnumpy.html). This is a very general statement, though; YMMV. Also, speaking of Matlab, there does indeed appear to be a bug in the looping indices.

Third, this may not be the best benchmark for performance; there may be some unseen caching issues taking place under the hood that aren't obvious. A better one would be to randomly generate the matrices on-the-fly in each iteration and multiply them, but even this could be problematic depending on the random number generator.

Comment: His benchmark isn't doing any looped computation though.  His loop only runs through the benchmarking iterations.

Comment: True, but simply creating the list with `range` incurs a performance penalty in Python 2. In Python 3 everything is a generator so it shouldn't be nearly as much of an (or really any) issue.

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you mean--somehow missed the part where he timed only the portion of computation inside the loop itself. Editing my post; thanks @BrenBarn

Comment: `np.dot` will usually call an external BLAS routine, which may very well use multiple cores depending on which BLAS library numpy is linked against at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in your Matlab code.  It appears that you are using the same loop control variable in nested loops.

The outer loop actually only runs once.

Edit:  The outer loop actually runs the correct number of times.  The two loop control variables seem to be independent.

Comment: The outer loop runs 4 times, regardless of the duplicate variable. For a simple example run `for i=1:3 for i=1:3 disp(i), end, end`

Comment: I would never try something like that.  It just doesn't look right to me.  @Daniel, your code, and the original work as expected.  Looks like I need to freshen up on my Matlab scoping rules.  Thanks for the new info.

Comment: I think everybody should be aware of such nonsense

Comment: What this anserw states is not true

Answer (score 0):

There are two major issues I can see with the test.

The first is that you are using global variable lookup in Python while you are using local variable lookup in MATLAB.  Global variable lookup in Python is relatively slow.  Making sure the variables are local like they are in MATLAB will affect the performance.

The second is that you are re-doing the same calculation over and over.  MATLAB has a JIT for loops and numpy has a cache for calculations, both of which can reduce the time for repeated calculations.

So to make the comparisons more equal and reliable, you should create new, random matrices each time through the loop.  This will prevent caching and JIT from messing up your results, and will make sure the variables are all local.